# Core Data not saving directly to sqlite

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data

In the old days, when I developed iOS app using Core Data for < iOS 7, I remembered that if I am not mistaken, sqlite file in emulator was not saved directly. I need to go to Home in iPad, then the sqlite file was updated.

Now I faced same thing. I observe my sqlite file never get modified, **only the SHM and WAL file**. So how can I check my data in sqlite?

The data is being persisted by Core Data since my app can fetch the new inserted/updated data.

Any advices from anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally after some research, because I copy and paste the 3 sqlite files from emulator to desktop, it seems the files lost all link and the data isn't displayed. Open the sqlite file directly inside emulator, works!